# How to store a "primary" record

Tags: database, database-design

Suppose I have the following tables

```
Companies
--CompanyID
--CompanyName
```

and

```
Locations
--LocationID
--CompanyID
--LocationName
```

Every company has at least one location.  I want to track a `primary` location for each company (and yes, every company will have exactly one primary location).  What's the best way to set this up?  Add a `primaryLocationID` in the `Companies` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add a primaryLocationID in the Companies table?

Yes, however that creates a circular reference which could prevent you from inserting new data:

[image]

One way to resolve this chicken-and-egg problem is to simply leave `Company.PrimaryLocationID` NULL-able, so you can temporarily disable one of the circular FKs. This unfortunately means the database will enforce only "1:0..1", but not the strict "1:1" relationship (so you'll have to enforce it in the application code).

However, if your DBMS supports deferred constraints (such as Oracle or PostgreSQL), you can simply defer one of the FKs to break the cycle while the transaction is still in progress. By the end of the transaction both FKs have to be in place, resulting in a real "1:1" relationship.

---

The alternative solution is to have a flag in the `Locations` table that is set for a primary location, and NULL non-primary locations (note the `U1`, denoting a UNIQUE constraint, ensuring a company cannot have multiple primary locations):

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Location (
    LocationID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CompanyID INT NOT NULL, -- References Company table, not shown here.
    LocationName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, -- Possibly UNIQUE?
    IsPrimary INT CHECK (IsPrimary IS NULL OR IsPrimary = 1), -- Use a BIT or BOOLEAN if supported by your DBMS.
    CONSTRAINT Locations_U1 UNIQUE (CompanyID, IsPrimary)
);
```

Unfortunately, this has some problems:

- It can only guarantee up to "1:0..1" (but not the real "1:1") even on a DBMS that supports deferred constraints.
- It requires an additional index (in support to the UNIQUE constraint). Every index brings certain overhead, mostly for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE performance. Furthermore, secondary indexes in [clustered tables](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) contain copy of PK, which may make them "fatter" than expected.
- It depends on ANSI-compliant composite UNIQUE constraints, that allow duplicated rows if **any** (but not necessarily all) of the fields are NULL. Unfortunately not all DBMSes follow the standard, so the above would not work out-of-box under Oracle or MS SQL Server (but would work under PostgreSQL and MySQL). You could use a [filtered](http://sqlfool.com/2009/04/filtered-indexes-what-you-need-to-know/) unique index instead of the UNIQUE constraint to work-around that, but not all DBMSes support that either.

---

The [BaBL86's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20505020/533120) models M:N, while your requirement seems to be 1:N. Nonetheless, that model could be "coerced" into 1:N by placing a key on `{LocationID}` (and on `{CompanyID, TypeOfLocation}` to ensure there cannot be multiple locations of the same type for the same company), but is probably over-engineered for a simple "is primary" requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I think your own solution is the best one - this ensures that every company can only have one primary location. By making it a `NOT NULL` column, you can even enforce that every company should have a primary location.

Using [BaBL86's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20505020/1001110), you don't have those constraints: a company can have 0 - unlimited 'primary locations', which obviously shouldn't be possible.

Do note that, if you use foreign key constraints AND define primaryLocationID as a `NOT NULL` column, you'll run into problems, because you basically have a loop (Location points to Company, Company points to location). You cannot create a new Company (because it needs a primary location), nor can you create a new Location (because it needs a company).

Answer (score -1):

I do it with pivot table:

```
CompanyLocations
    --CompanyID
    --LocationID
    --TypeOfLocation (primary, office, warehouse etc.)
```

In this case you can select all locations and than use type as you like. If you create PrimaryLocationID - you're need two joins of one table and more complex logic. It's worst than this.

Comment: A location can be both primary and a warehouse - so that won't quite work.  I was considering something similar though - a boolean field "primaryLocation" for each record of the Locations table but this doesn't seem better than having a primaryLocationID in the companies table.

Comment: If you have a number of checkboxes, you can use binary mask (like Unix ACL): first bit is a primary flag, second - warehouse, third - office and your TypeOfLocation in this case: 1 - primary, 2 - warehouse, 3 - primary and warehouse, 4 - office, 5 - office and primary, 6 - office and warehose, 7 - office, warehouse and primary. Read about BEETWISE operations: where (TypeOfLocation&4=4) for example.